# How to concatenate command line arguments with separator

Tags: c++

I read from argv the arguments and i want to put them into only one string.
For example if the arguments are : `man` `ls` `-la`, then i want to get command string  `"man ls -la"` in one string

Here is what i currently have:

```
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char**argv) { 

    string command;
    for (int i = 1; i<argv; i++) {
        command += argv[i]; 
    }

    my_function(command); 
}
```

`command` should contain all the arguments separate by a space:

Is this correct ?

I also have a compiler error:

> error C2446: '<': no conversion from 'char **' to 'int'

Where is this error coming from?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. And what have you tried? This is the kind of thing any tutorial will cover. Also, please don't tag both c and c++. Which is it?

Comment: C++ . My question is : How i can get all the arguments from argv to only 1 string. If the arguments are : argv[1] = "man", argv[2] = "ls" , argv[3] = "-la"   how i can store all 3 to 1 string with name command, so that i have command = "man ls -la"  ?

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? If you print `command` what is the expected value? What is the actual value? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Changes are made to better understand the question

Answer (score 2):

A simple way:

```
std::string argument;
std::for_each( argv + 1, argv + argc , [&]( const char* c_str ){ argument += std::string ( c_str ) + " "; } );
std::cout << argument;
```

or write you `join` function:

```
struct Join{
    template< typename Container >
    std::string operator()( Container first, Container last,const std::string& delimiter = " " ){

        std::ostringstream oss;
        while( first != last ){
            ( ( first + 1 ) != last ) ? ( oss << *first << delimiter ) : ( oss << *first );
            ++first;
        }

        return oss.str();
    }
}join;
```

usage:

```
std::string result = join( argv + 1, argv + argc );
std::cout << result << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error you get is because you use `argv` in your for instead of `argc`, here is the correct version:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc;i++) {...}
```

You also need to add a space after each argument (except the last time)

```
for (int i = 1; i<argc; i++) {
    command += argv[i];

    if (i != argc-1) //this check prevents adding a space after last argument.
        command += " ";
}
```

or add the space before each argument (except the first time)

```
for (int i = 1; i<argc; i++) {
    if (i != 1)
        command += " ";

    command += argv[i];
}
```

Please note that you start your iteration from the first element (`for(int i = 1 ...`). This skips the first argument that is always the executable name.

Comment: argv[0] is the name of the executable, so the OP was right to start with 1

Comment: I don't see anything that says that man is the executable name, just that "the arguments are : man ls -la"

Comment: Again I fail to see any connection. The OP doesn't mention man as being the executable name, let alone the man command.